# How to avoid receiving an error message when the crawled website is down

Tags: ruby, sinatra, nokogiri

I am parsing some data from a website. Today the website was down with a 500 error and my application was down too because of the 500 issue.

I tried to use `x ? x : "not available"` but it gave me the same result, the application was down. How can I get my code to work even if the website is down?

```
num = Nokogiri::HTML (open('https://quotes.wsj.com/ETFM'))
@smh = num.css('.cr_data_collection') ? num.css('.cr_data_collection')[1].css('.data_data')[0].text : " details are not available"
```

Comment: You mean "I want it to fail elegantly, not crash out" presumably. You can't crawl a site that's down.

Comment: Yes, I want it to fail elegantly, so is it possible to print " the crawled site is down" or something like this when the site is not reached?

Comment: @ZeeZee Instead of `open('url')` you can use ruby [`Net::HTTP`](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.3.1/libdoc/net/http/rdoc/Net/HTTP.html) approach or some other gem like [`httparty`](https://github.com/jnunemaker/httparty), [`faraday`](https://github.com/lostisland/faraday) and such so send a request and check [`response http code`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status). If its 500 you print something out. Check out this article on [`how to make http requests in ruby`](https://www.rubyguides.com/2018/08/ruby-http-request/)

Comment: Or you just catch an error `open('url')` raises with [`begin-rescue block`](http://rubylearning.com/satishtalim/ruby_exceptions.html). Your app crashes because you dont handle that

Comment: Have you considered creating a background task that would periodically crawl the third-party website and store a local copy of the data, either in a database or on the local file system (depending on its size and format). If your app always references the local copy, it could continue working even when the third-party website is down.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/q/21081639/128421. Ping the other device prior to trying to connect. If you can't ping it then loop and sleep some appropriate amount of time to avoid deluging that device with ping requests possibly swamping it or irritating its, or your, network admin.

Comment: Thank you @theTinMan, I will have a look at.